# How many projects can we create in big query? Is there any limitations on number of projects?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

For one account how many projects I can create in google big query

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas

Comment: What do you mean by creating project in BigQuery?

Answer (score 1):

When you go through the create a new project flow, you should see a banner appear at the top advising you how many projects you have left to create.

I don't believe there's a hard and fast rule of how many projects you're allowed, as the support articles note the quota cap increases the more you use the platform. For me I'm allowed 25 more projects currently, but you can request more projects if you hit the limit, you may have to pay for this though.

[Quota Request](https://support.google.com/code/contact/project_quota_increase?authuser=1)